# Toggle a setting using shortcut

Tags: functions

I have set up Vim to trigger reformatting on save using ALE, but sometimes that doesn't fly very well, and  would like to disable it manually. But remembering what the right incantations are is always impossible, needing to grep my dotfiles for clues, so I'd like to be able to toggle it, say, using Alt-F8. That means some kind of vimscript function that just sets `let g:ale_fix_on_save = 0`.

How would such a function look and how do I bind it?

(Bonus points for showing how to toggle the value)

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for a rudimentary mapping with a single assignment statement. Are you having trouble setting this up? What have you tried? FYI, you can toggle with `let x = !x`.

Answer (score 2):

[While [B Layer is right](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22138/toggle-a-setting-using-shortcut#comment40044_22138) that this question should demonstrate attempts (in order that answers address conceptual misunderstandings), the answer is at least straightforward.]

To toggle a "boolean" variable:

```
let x = !x
```

So the mapping is simply

```
nnoremap <your keys> :let g:ale_fix_on_save = !g:ale_fix_on_save<CR>
```

Comment: Thank you. Of course I had to try and make this work using the Alt key plus F keys, which Google quickly showed involved a world of pain trying to make work in ever changing environments. Mapped it to F9 to avoid further troubles.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the first sentence. BLayer is right...but...what?

Comment: @BLayer do you mean you have trouble with its meaning or parsing the structure? If former, perhaps I meant to really say that I was asking the same questions as you were in the comments, but Im going to answer anyway—if latter, a stripped version is « while BLayer is right (blah), the answer is at least straightforward »

Comment: @BLayer I’ve edited slightly

Comment: So...we want questioners to demonstrate effort but we're not going to hold them to it so here's the answer...? Why'd I bother mentioning it? Should've just answered, I guess.

Comment: @BLayer I understand this is a sore spot for you—I think for me, what I saw was a decent (not high quality, but not garbage) question: and I value helping the person on the other end get to an answer. I suppose I could have been more of a teacher in this answer, and explained how to get help, and pointed to references on creating mappings, etc., it was a quick and dirty « this will work ». I would greatly welcome an answer of higher quality that teaches OP how to fish... but I’m not going to get tangled in knots about the question itself

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm definitely not a fan of the emergence of point-grabbing as the primary motivator that seems to be the new norm (esp. among some newer arrivals).